# What is the difference between npm prestart and npm poststart?

Tags: npm, package, npm-scripts, npm-start

I am familiar with `npm start`, but I don't know what does the **prestart** and **poststart** do exactly.
Which script is runned before start (i.e.: pre or post). I wanna know to proper flow of it...?

After doing some research I found prestart is called first than start is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we set up our `scripts` properly then simply running the command `npm start` will be able to handle all of our needs in the proper order.
It's has huge useful for many situations where we need something to happen immediately before or immediately after a **primary action**.( `npm start`) Here You have [reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts).

### Example

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "node first.js",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "poststart": "node last.js"
  }
}
```

---

`prestart` starts first before `npm start` and `poststart` is fired last.

Comment: In short, we just need to fire `npm start` command, it will execute the `prestart` command and than `start` command and at last `poststart` command. There are also other things like `precompress`, `prebuild`, etc.

Comment: @DhruvParmar Exactly :-) In short obviously ...